# How target routes with 'lang?' in a middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this middleware:

```
app
.use('/:lang?', middleware.setLanguage)
.use('/thanks/:lang?', middleware.setLanguage)
.use('/forum/:lang?', middleware.setLanguage);
```

I want use a function called setLanguage in every route that have lang?, and currently this code is working, but i can believe dry that.

Someone knows how to? I search in the documentation, but didn't find anything..

Answer (score 0):

Use .param to process the parameters up front so that you don't have to do it on every route that uses it. For example, here's one that starts building a query with moongoose for a product crud:

```
  app.param('product_id', function (req, res, next, product_id) {
    req.product_id = new ObjectId(product_id);
    req.product = Product.findOne(req.product_id);
    next();
  });

  // update product
  app.put('/products/:product_id', function (req, res) {
    Product.findOneAndUpdate(req.product_id, req.body, function (err, product) {
      res.json(product.toObject());
    });
  });

  // get product by id
  app.get('/products/:product_id', function (req, res) {
    req.product.lean().exec(function (err, product) {
      res.json(product);
    });
  });
```

None of my routes have to get the product id and convert it to an ObjectId because i did that up front for all routes with .param.

Comment: hm, i don't know if this is a good idea, because the user can change the language, for example: if he is in the forum/espanol, and he wants to go to the forum/english, this option will be a problem, right?

Comment: I don't see how it would perform any differently than what you are currently doing, other than only writing it once. No matter what route they  hit, if that route includes :lang, it would run through the .param that matches it.

Comment: Though, i've never seen a param used with a `?` like you're doing. is that something special? or is it just treated as part of the string.

Comment: the ? make the parameter optional, so i can make a main language, for example... req.params.lang = req.params.lang || 'en', so if the user didn't type parameter, the language will be en, get it?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. My example wouldn't cover that specific case, it would need it's own middleware that initializes the value that .param then overwrites if needed. Your existing solution may be best for your case

Comment: but please don't delete your answer, someday i can use app.param and your example is good.. hahaha..

Comment: I would try using my solution, along with an `app.use(function (req, res, next) {req.lang = 'en';next();});` to initialize the value to english in the event no language is passed.

Comment: hm, but how to use app.use middleware.setLanguage in every route that have a 'lang?' without typing one by one?

Comment: do you have any routes that don't have `:lang?` Do you care if the setLanguage middleware runs on those routes too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70738/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-drx).